# What should be the regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have string

```
     str = "Value((10 20,30 40),(50 60,70 80,90 100))"
```

What should be the regular expression to get the value in the following format :

option 1:

```
strArray[0]  = 10 20 , 30 40;
strArray[1] = 50 60 , 70 80 , 90 100;
```

option 2

```
strArray[0][0] = 10 20
strArray[0][1] = 30 40
strArray[1][0] = 50 60
strArray[1][1] = 70 80
strArray[1][2] = 90 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
"Value((10 20,30 40),(50 60,70 80,90 100))"
  .split('),(')
  .map(function(x){
    return x.replace(/value|\(|\)/gi,'').split(',')
  });
//=>[["10 20", "30 40"], ["50 60", "70 80", "90 100"]]
```

Comment: Nice solution. My answer is similar but ill post it anyway for the sake of choice xD.

Comment: @elclanrs, but your answer doesn't do what OP is looking for ;)

Comment: what is the meaning of split('),(') ?

Comment: and what is the meaning of /value|\(|\)/gi,'' ?

Comment: what is the meaning of Google?

Comment: @user1365697: MDN is your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions ;)